# Cannot destroy one module using Terraform destroy

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have created a few instances using Terraform module:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "cluster" {
  count = var.num_instances
  name = "redis-${format("%03d", count.index)}"
  ...
  attached_disk {
    source = 
google_compute_disk.ssd[count.index].name
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "ssd" {
  count   = var.num_instances
  name    = "redis-ssd-${format("%03d", count.index)}"
  ...
  zone    = data.google_compute_zones.available.names[count.index % length(data.google_compute_zones.available.names)]

}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "dns" {
  count   = var.num_instances
 name    = "${var.dns_name}-${format("%03d", 
count.index +)}.something.com"
  ...

  managed_zone = XXX

  rrdatas = [google_compute_instance.cluster[count.index].network_interface.0.network_ip]
}

module "test" {
  source = "/modules_folder"
  num_instances             = 2
    ...
}
```

How can I destroy one of the instances and its dependency, say instance[1]+ssd[1]+dns[1]? I tried to destroy only one module using

```
terraform destroy -target module.test.google_compute_instance.cluster[1]
```

but it does not destroy ssd[1] and it tried to destroy both dns:

module.test.google_dns_record_set.dns[0]
module.test.google_dns_record_set.dns[1]

if I run

```
terraform destroy -target module.test.google_compute_disk.ssd[1]
```

it tried to destroy both instances and dns:

module.test.google_compute_instance.cluster[0]
module.test.google_compute_instance.cluster[1]

module.test.google_dns_record_set.dns[0]

module.test.google_dns_record_set.dns[1]

as well.

how to only destroy instance[1], ssd[1] and dns[1]? I feel my code may have some bug, maybe count.index has some problem which trigger some unexpected destroy?

I use: Terraform v0.12.29

Comment: output of `terraform state list` prior to the attempted destroy would be illustrative.

Comment: If you want to destroy the module's resources, then why not target the module?

Comment: @MattSchuchard: I did target. see my command in the post: terraform destroy -target module.test.google_compute_instance.cluster[1]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused as to why you want to `terraform destroy` what you'd normally want to do is decrement `num_instances` and then `terraform apply`.

If you do a `terraform destroy` the next `terraform apply` will put you right back to whatever you have configured in your terraform source.

It's a bit hard without more of your source to see what's going on- but setting `num_instances` on the module and using it in the module's resources feels wonky.

I would recommend you upgrade terraform and use `count` or `for_each` directly on the module rather than within it. (this was introduced in terraform `0.13.0`) see https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-13-brings-powerful-meta-arguments-to-modular-workflows

Comment: use case is: suppose one of the instances I created using above terraform has some issue and I want to destroy it and relaunch a new one. I do not think I can use auto-scaling to do that  because after an instance is launched, I need to run several redis-cli commands manually to join the new node to redis cluster and reshard it with hash-slot. That is way I want to destroy and relaunch it manually using the above terraform so that it is within my control.

Answer (score 1):

Remove resource by resource:

```
terraform destroy -target RESOURCE_TYPE.NAME -target RESOURCE_TYPE2.NAME


resource "resource_type" "resource_name" {
   ...
}
```